# How do I make an HTML footer take up the remaining height of the page without it being fixed or with JS?

Tags: html, css

For example, I want [this page](https://www.starstreet.com/daily_games/51555) to have the footer fill to the bottom of the page, but I want [this page](https://www.starstreet.com/pickfive) to behave how it does now - so the footer cannot be fixed. I'd prefer to not use JS simply because `$(window).resize()` is expensive and performance is a concern for us.

Our lowest supported browser is IE9, Firefox 13, Chrome 16 and Safari 5 so I'm not concerned about using a more advanced solution, though probably not bleeding-edge.

Comment: can't make your second url work :(

Comment: Whoops my bad, fixed it thanks!

Comment: did the solutions below work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - you have to either calculate the window height and footer top offset (which involves JS), or fix the position of the element to `bottom: 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the page background color match the footer color, and instead of using the graphic as the background for the whole page, make it only for the content area.

so put the background on main-content-container

and make the body background color #EBEBEB

Comment: Sorry that's just not possible, otherwise I would have implemented that a while ago. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, but it does bring other problems with it.  You will need to set a min-height and make sure your content does not exceed that min-height or it may get cut off and all text must be at the top of the second div.

The css:

```
body,html
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
div#wrapper
{
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 600px;
}
div#one
{
 background-color: #0ff;
 height: 200px;
}
div#two
{
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #f00;
}
```

The html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

So the content on the bottom, would not be able to exceed 400px in height in this example.  But, if it was larger than that it would be filled in by a solid color.

Comment: Wouldn't imposing a `min-height` cause a scrollbar to appear for every single page we have?

Comment: @acconrad only if the user's browser window is less than the min-height of the #wrapper div.

Comment: [Here is a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UM4n/1/) showing the solution I've came up with.

Comment: It broke as soon as I entered data into the first div... [see the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UM4n/2/)

Comment: @acconrad it broke because I had a fixed height set on the example of the first div to make it appear.  Removing it in your updated I got [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plowdawg/8UM4n/3/)  The biggest problem I think is your footer could potentially disappear.

Comment: @acconrad here is [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/plowdawg/8UM4n/7/) that may be a little better, this one maintains the footer, adds a scrollbar to the upper div if it goes above it's max-height.